# Is there any way to impose user validation with yum?

Tags: rhel, yum, authentication

I am trying to set up a package distribution via yum. Is there any way to restrict who can install the package from the server side (running RHEL 7.1)?

I imagine that it is possible by whitelisting specific addresses requesting the rpm, but this does not seem very robust. I was hoping that yum would be able to tie some sort of authentication request to the server request.

This might not be possible, but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do this. When it's an http transport, it's just a regular web server and so you have all the access control mechanisms. You can do HTTP Basic auth, authentication via client SSL certs, host-based access control (as you mentioned) etc. It really depends on what you have available. Once you figure out how to secure the web site, you configure yum to access it in accordance with whatever policy you've set up.

Comment: You can [look at the `yum.conf` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/yum.conf) for the different mechanisms. For instance `username` and `password` as well as `sslclientcert`

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might be enough. This is my first time configuring a package server and I was not thinking about it like a regular web server.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

In theory you could add a program to the `%pre` pre-install section.  If this returns a non-zero exit code then install fails.  However a user could always do an install with `--no-script`.

And even if such enforcement was possible, an rpm is really a wrappered cpio file; a user could do `rpm2cpio` to convert it and then extract the files directly.

Basically, the rpm format isn't a copy-protected container and can't be used to enforce any sort of access control or licensing scheme.

Comment: This doesn't address their concern, they're asking about repo access control.

Comment: Right, I am more concerned with access control. I had originally thought that I wanted to protect the rpm, but just protecting the download is enough for this use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pulp (https://docs.pulpproject.org/) to set up the yum repositories, then require authentication to allow access to consumers.  It would be much like a subscription-manager style of authentication, using client-side SSL certs.